# HTML email template images are not displaying in Outlook and Webmail

Tags: html, css

Thanks Everybody in advance, I have created an email template with banner image and with some widget image.

Actually instead of giving the path of the image which is stored in the server I used a code which is the decode of base64.

I used https://www.base64-image.de/ this online converter will convert the image to base64 decode for my image.

Actually my plan is instead of loading the image from the server I was using the base64 decode image so that it will be displayed in all emails like Outlook and web mail.

By referring the google I got this idea but in outlook and web mail it's not working.

After converting the image using https://www.base64-image.de/ I got the image code like this

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAgGBgcGERIHBwcVFRMQFhkYFxAVERgYFxMWFxYXGBMVFRYVJCMfGhcgGhcgICsdICcxKCsoHxswMS8mMC4uKCYBCQkJDQwNFw0OGTIhFx0wMjItMioyJzIyJzImMicmMi0mLDEqLTIyJiYyJiYmJi0tMjImLTImJiYyJiYmJiYmMv/AABEIAGMCtAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAEAAwEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABAUGAwIHAf/EAEgQAAEDAgMEBwYCBgcHBQAAAAEAAgMEEQUSIRQVMVQGEyJBkqLRMjNRcoGyYXEjQlORobEHFkNik7PBJDRSVXPh8CVEZMPx/8QAGgEBAAIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEAQIFBv/EACgRAQABAwMCBAcAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEESExBRJBcdHwBjIzUWGhwf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A+4UVFSujjc6mYSWtucg10C77BR8ozwBKD3UfyN+0KQgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgj7BR8ozwBNgo+UZ4ApCII+wUfKM8ATYKPlGeAKQiCPsFHyjPAE2Cj5RngCkIgyuPxRwyBsUYAyjQADvd8EXvpH71vyD7nIgv6D3UfyN+0KQo9B7qP5G/aFIQEREBEXKWeKHWR4C0ruU0R3VTpDMRrw6oqubGGDSJl/xOir5q6om9p/0Gi4WX8SYlnaie6fx6p6MaurnZeTVsEHtSa/BflJVNqgXNbaxss4rnBvZd+f8AoFS6Z12/m5cW5jSjf3q3u2KaKNfFZoiL1qoIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiICIiAiIgIiIMx0j9635B9zkTpH71vyD7nIgv6H3UfyN/kFIUeg91H8jftC7Pa52jXWWJnSAc9rNXOUKbFYI9Gdo/h6rqaGF2sl3H8Sf5Lqynhj9iMD6KhejMubUTFEffmf5CSOyOd1TJW1tRpGwgfgP8AVchh1XLq5n1JWgsPgi5tfQIvT3ZF2qr9QljI7fljRTMwaQ+3KB9F3Zg8I9pxKskVq10HBt8Ua+e7Sci5Piisw+lZwiH11/mpDWNZo0WXpF0rWPatfTpiPKEU1TPMiIimYEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREGY6R+9b8g+5yJ0j9635B9zkQX9B7qP5G/aFBxfpHh2CFsda9wLwSLNJ0HHgp1B7qP5G/aFgP6S/ewfI7+YQaD+v+A/tn/wCG5dqTprgta9tNFM7M82F2EC54C6+YYRhNRjUmyUpaHWLu0bCwtfhf4q+H9HmNDUSxfnnd6INnXdMcJw6R1JVOeHMOo6s/mCD3hScI6R4bjZdHRSklgBILSND3i/H/APFlul+BVc9PHidQ0GaFuWUt1Dm/8Xdw4/UrH4Jij8HnZWs4NNnD4tPtD938bIPs1fXU+Gxuq6p9ms4n+AAHeVQ/1/wH9s//AA3LOdPsdZWlmHUsl2NAe4jgSR2B9Ab/AFCrOh2Cb4nD5Wfo4rOd8Cf1W/U6/kCg+s08zahrZmtIDgCARY2PC47l0REBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEWKqnR1NbUwVuPyQNYI8jW1AjBvGC6wdp+74q6pcLZJBJFSYzLIJfZmM+YtI0GVzbaXGo/NBdosa3pJUspjRuH+2B3UZe8v4CT8ra34XWow2lkoomU8s7nuaO09ziS495udbX4fgglIshjkjZK5tLU4xJBH1Ga7ZurBd1jh36Xt9dF1rKWHCqaWuZjlS9rg20nWiQi72i8fAa3sTfhdBqkVTinSCkwcxMqI3kzXy5Wgm7QNCL3ucwAsvWFY7S4sXwxxvY+O2aORmVwB4G2uiC0RUdd0opaBzopqOfKw2dKIjkb+blJxPHaPCo2Vs1yyRzWgtF/aBcHd2lh3aoLNFT4d0jpMQk2LqJI32zBsrMpcPi1ea/pNR0LzSiGSRzBd/VR5urB/wCI9yC6RVtTjtDTRMri5xbLbI1rSXPJ1Aa3jdMLxqmxUujjjex7LZo5G5XgHgbfBBZIqnpHiMmGU754YnlxBALG3yEtJD3fBotx/JV/R7Eo6SjNfXzzWBBc6fUklrfdd5jJPZ+qDTIqag6TUddIKQwyRueLtEseXOP7vG651nSqkpJX4fskz3x2JEcea4LQ6414C4veyC9RfjXZgHWtfuPEfms9L0yoY3SRCkmcYXOa8tjBDcpsXEg6N0P46cEGiRQX4xQxwb0dP+iIvm+N+AtxvfSyiUHSajrpBSGGSNzxdoljy5x/d43QXKKirOlVJSSyYfssz3x2JbHHmuC0OuLHgLi97KbSY1QVkO8WVAbHwLnkNym9rOvwN/8ARBYIs70mxNj6Kaqw2tBLS0dZG/gc7LjM06Gx/iuGH4TR1ZDqbpRUSFtiWtqw794A4INSiosOxKKNlZUumkeIJZcwcBduQXLI9dW6aXt9Fyh6Z4dNkJglayQgCV0dmZj+rmvxvppog0SKDieKMwwNe+mkeXGwbGwuK84VjNLi4cYA4Fhs5j25XNPdcILBFmY+nOGyNFQKWfJezpOq7LDf9Yg/yurfEMYo8NjFVPJcOsGhouXk8A0d6CeirMNxymxPOxsMkbowC5krMpAPA/C2nxUSLpbh0rms6uQMe7K2d0ZETjwADv8AsgvkRZ2Xpnh8LpIzTTHqXlj3CO7W2NsxIOjSeHf+CDRIqKn6WYdUyNpmMkAkNmSmO0bz8GuPHX8FLxPGY8MLWOo5pC4XtFGXWA+J0CCyRVtPjlHVQPxSEksjDi5trOGQXc2x71Xw9M8OmyEwStZIQBK6OzMx/VzX43000QaJFBxPFGYYGvfTSPLjYNjYXFeMMxukxVr3xZmmM2ex4yuZ8wQWKLNS9N8MiaZzTzFgNmyCLsvN7EMcSPz1twVniWN02G5A+N73SezFG3M8gcTb4BBZIqunx6jqoZK+MOtCHF7C2z2louQWnvt+K4UHSijxC746aVrAwvMro7MAb7QzX1I/BBdoqSg6T0uIPbDHSTND/ZkdEQx9hfRwv3DvV2gzHSP3rfkH3OROkfvW/IPuciC/oPdR/I37QsB/SX72D5HfzC39B7qP5G/aFgP6S/ewfI7+YQZTCsVqcHk2qkIzWI1FxY2vp9Fd/wBf8d/44/8AD/7qH0Tjw2Soy4rk6vI72zYZri3HvW52ToT/APG8bfVBeYbK7EKeOWpAJljBcLaHM3XT4ar5H0iwd2CTupbdk9ph+LTw+o4L61Q4jhT8tHQ1cZyizWNeDYD4AdwWU/pLa3JA62uZwv8AhYaIPnjGOkIYxtyTYAd5OgC+0dHMGbgkDab9c9p5+Ljx+g4fRfMuh7WurYA5t9SfqGOIX2NBl8exmsop9lhqQxoiz+4dKS7MRbs8BYcVJpek0Zi6+qiOZkDZnhliLOvo0349ngpNfgr6uXbYMRfE7JkOQNN25i79YHW5UKfojTOaIKeskjb1XVOAynO25cLlw43J1HxQfj8elZKI+t7HXFrrstlYIOssCCb69/0UeXpRPMXPjidGzqmPaXRgudnla0OAzeyWnvsQplZg1BSB9fVVDsrXGRwt3dT1RGmtsuv5qMejtPC1rJq6V4kayJvZByNa8SMvlGg7NiSgns6S0zpNmdTSAdY6PrSBkzsBJGhvwB1svWGdIYcUeIGUsjczDI1zwAHsuAHCxJ1v3r93BTusDMTad01tNS8OBb8vaUHBcEqcPqDI6Rxiii6uPO5pJBcHaZRo0AW7WqCeMfp9o3Y6MhxJAddhBIFzo0lw0+IUWXpE6kqJaWop3GNhib1jQLMMg4vJN9XEDQL3T9GYaeZtY2qdZj3yBlm2BkBzXdbMRrpcr1V9HY6uV9S6teGyOjc+IZcrurtkubXAuPig4T9LaYdYynhcXNbJkPZtIY/bsAbgDjra4BsuVN0kqpH08c1C4NliL3usNLZe0NdGC9/jq1dI8GoKKU0u0u/2hsuWLI3QH3hD7ZtM2gJ70p8Ip3PjpRiL3PpWZXXa3txScGO0tazOI1QfrOmNA9rphC/shrg2zSXte4Ma5oB01PA2PBXlJO6pYJnwOYT+o62Ya99rhUsPRSCFhpdqcW3Zl7DAWhjw4DMAC69rElaBAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERBhaiswSkr6s40xhBEWXNEX/wBmM1rA27lpsFxTCK9phwhwyxWu1sZYG5iSLAgcSDwVoiDLvpod6tf1Yvs2a/8Aezlt/wA8ui1CIgy1ZSU9ZibYqqBr27LfK5ocL9a7Wx7126YwxwUEsUMYa0ZLNAsB+kZwAWjRBmcWANXh1x+1+xq9x6Yo63fS/wD2haNEHzGrrH1EU4xHEqkVHbvTNBEYbrxFrZLcTdXeJgGjw0Ef2lN/llbNEGcxUf8AqFCfwm/y1CpcTg6NzVUWJNcOukMjHhhIkDuDQR3jhqtgiDIdJ2uq20mKETRxsJL8nZljD2izu+1ra/mpHRmmw6aR+I0VfUSkNyZ5iSCCQ7skgE2I+l/xWnRBWdIv91qP+k/7SqTEKaafD6SSGIv6kQSOYOLmtYLgDv43+i1yIMfVYlB0lnpY8MY49TIJHyFhAYBxaSe88FNwoDeFcbd0P+WtGiAsx0baDt9xxqZVp0QYGnpp6jC6aWGIv6mXrHMGpc1sslwB38f4KdVYlB0lnpY8MY49TIJHyFhAYBxaSe88FsEQZzCgN4Vxt3Q/5a59FqeGojq4J4WuaaqTsOaCNMhGh04rTogzPS2kpqOgnjpadrASw5WNDRfrGa2Hforqhw+iowH0tIxhcBctYGk/nZTEQYyi/wB3xX/q1H2FeMXAGER2HBkX82rbIgyXSirlhniiqq2WGmLCTJFe5kueySASBa3/AJw59DC0z1hbLI4Xis6X23DK+xd9P4WWrqaymowH1VQ1gJsC9waCfhc966RyMlAkjeCDwINwfyIQYvCGjc8mn6kv83L3VB8EOG4oYi6OBjc4AuQHRtAfb8LLXS1EEOkszRoXakDsi2Z2vcLjX8V6kljiGeR4A0FybC5NgNfiTZBTMxSn6RRT0+HB2sZaJSwtaXOaQACdbhZTDqTDq1seFVmI1gl0a6nuS1hHfYtIDARp8F9EMsYIiLxmIJDb6kCwJt8BcfvC/BUQnMBM3se1qOzpftfDTXVB0WMogDT4rp/a1H2lbGORkoEkbwQ4XDgbgg8CCOIXpBiawAUeGkD+2g+1y9Y5WPbVPgxHEZ4Yg1vVdTcdYSO1ctBub938u/ZOkYwhrngFxsATxNibD46AlekGGwK+wV9y72p/b9r3Q9r+98fxXvFwBhEdhwZF/Nq2YljJMQeMwAJbfUA3sbfDQrztMGUz9e3K2935hlGUkOueAsRYoMv0oq5YZ4oqqtlhpiwkyRXuZLnskgEgWt/5wg9HoXVZxGCCWRxexjWvl0eczJA0uv8An+6y2dNXUlbc0tUx9uOR4db87KQg+cV+N0rsO3T1TxKxrGuZkIyZXtu5x4AG37yrPpHAIaiGvqqmaOExZDLCSCxwObtWB7Jv/BXOJ4BJi7warEXdTcHZw0AEj4u4kE9yu0GQpKSiZSVlbR1Mz+ujfd83E5GOAIuASCDx/BWuE9U2gi62Iub1AuwC5cMmoAHElXAkYSYw8XABLb6gG9iR+Nj+4r0gwmHYlHTTQ0mB1ksjHOs+nkYT1Te8hxAIt8Fu0RBmOkfvW/IPucidI/et+Qfc5EF/Qe6j+Rv2hY3p7hGI4lJC+ipHPDWuBItoSRbitlQe6j+Rv2hSEHxf+quPf8rf/D1T+quO/wDKn/w9V9oRB826G4DitBVNqKqhc1oa4Zja1yNOBV109wytxJkLaKmLy1ziQLaC34rXog+X9Fuj+L0dXFUVNA5rWl13G1h2XD4r6giIMp0kwivrJQaK4bIztuB4OiJfF+9xsq2fCK9zGSVeHvkdJHIcrXW6qokfmDjqLWFhfust6iDFS4DUyMrJqimL5iwNY+/tfoWtfl7tXXXWmwzEYMkM0TnObVMkdN+0YYzqddMp7NvyWwRBg4MBr6eJmyUzmSyU8zZDmtd5LTGHG/HjY9yseijIRLUtgpDG0CIdW62hyuzcCVq1yhp4KYFsELWgm5DWgXJ4k27/AMUGGj6P4uHiJzT1fWdSRf8A9u1/WB/19lejhOJXky0TxJlqOsmzdmcPa7qWt114jS2llvEQYypwCohbFHhtMWuNPKHOvwlcyMC5J9o2IupvReidTSTSsw50LHNiDWutclodn4E95WmRAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERAREQEREBERBU4yTG+mnMLnNZI4uyRueQDFI0EhoJtchVksFfHC51LG6NslQXZA12ZsRbY9iMhwu8ZrNN7E/ktSiDI11HXSR2cHyO2SYZurcCS58ZY0g3OawtYm5sVLlgrqV7oIHzOZnpnAlzncZSJgHH9XKASOAB7gtGiCukikNVHKGHKIZAXW0BL4iBf4mx/cVSTYdXPlqOqjcGVEmR51HYbHG4Ob8b9tlx3kfBaxEGOz4jRU5hbDNd1JE2MMa85JGtcHjT2Haj4cFLqaWuldLM2acHaI2tDXvA6pwiEhDeFtXdruIPBaZEGUqaeoY5sczZ3RxVDrOb1jniM0/EOHaIzuIve/clS7FTBDE5soJzkvAkLxZ36FrxEQblp1LtARqtWiClwR1c92esD9YIPaBA6y0nWaHQO4X+ijvppzQTwdQ7M7r7MynMc0khbYcTcHRaJEGYpmVjnyz0pkc7qHNbJLD1ZEgN2NaMrQQbkk20sNVyp4MSdCQamY5pYRbJKx7Bnb1pBe5zi2x1t2RY9y1iIMzK2sga6F7pjEyosXAvMhiMQIs4dotEhtca2uoYnr6iniELpSHOmPW/pXP0kcI2u6og6jvJyiy18kUcwMcrAWnQtIuCPgQV+sYyIBkbAAOAAsAPwCDKxjEgNrdFJn6ujL7NIc7K9xmbYcTY6t/FdmisxB9j17Y3VLv2jCIxTi3wLWF4/f+K0yIM5US10L30rWTHNURFrgHloi/RB4z8ANHXB+JWjREGY6R+9b8g+5yJ0j9635B9zkQRWYxXxARsn0AsBlbwHDuXrfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgb7xHmPK30TfeI8x5W+iIgi1NVNVnrJ33IFr2A0+n5oiIP/9k="" width="692" height="99" border="0">`  Please help me

Comment: You appear to have two double quotes (`""`) at the end of src attribute, that might explain the breakage, but it's more likely to be the issue I outline below.

Answer (score 0):

The email client is probably blocking this type of image, or in fact *any* image by default. I imagine they believe that base64 encoded images present too much of risk in terms of malicious attack.

When designing emails you should expect that images will **never** be seen, so make good use of alt text and never have important information (e.g. text) in images on emails.

A lot of html emails include a "email looks wrong? view online HERE" link to get around this issue.

If you are worried about server costs for image hosting I would suggest using a service that will send and host resources for you e.g Mailchimp and Campaign Monitor.

These are good resources on the subject:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/image-blocking-in-email/

http://templates.mailchimp.com/design/images/